# How to manually set Symfony command sorting order?

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

Is it possible to set sort order for Symfony commands manually? Such as

```
$this
    ->setName('say:hello')
    ->setDescription('Example description')
    ->setOrder(1);
```

I want to sorting my commands manually instead of sorting DESC by name like default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API:

http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.html

I don't see a method to do that in the API. So the answer is most likely no.